# Slack-App-Watson: Watson looses intent from previous message received

Tags: node.js, ibm-watson, watson-conversation, watson

I am writing a simple Slack bot which can look for weather conditions for a given location.

In the Watson conversation chat box, Watson is doing good:

> - me: Weather please
> - Watson (detected #weather_asked): Where do you want to know the weather conditions?
> - me: Paris
> - Watson (detected @location for intent #weather_asked): Finding weather conditions for Paris...

But in my node.js app (connected to Slack), it seems that Watson is "*not keeping in mind that I am providing a location for the #weather_asked intent*":

> - me: Weather please
> - Watson (detected #weather_asked): Where [...]?
> - me: Paris
> - Watson (detected only @location and intent #location_given): I am sorry, I did not understand. (fallback anything_else)

It is like Watson, when used through my NodeJS app, is forgetting the initial intent #weather_asked and is "reset" to its primary Dialogs. What am I missing?

Screenshot of my Watson Conversation Dialogs configuration: https://i.stack.imgur.com/t68fN.jpg

**edit:** I found out my app sends the user's input to Watson with a new conversation ID. I will try to set this context if it already exists.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the solution! The problem was that I did not tell Watson my user had already started a conversation with him (it?).

I made a simple piece of code which stores the existing context grouped by Slack's user_id. If a context already exists for this user_id, then my app will call Watson API and append this context to the request, so Watson knows that this new User's input follows a previous one.